# Is the Lorentz force a vector field or just a vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, definition, vector-fields

I've heard both yes and no.

Is the Lorentz force a vector field or just a vector?
$$\mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B})$$

Comment: Please define your notion of vector field :)

Comment: @Sanya For a vector field I mean $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r})=A_x(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat x}+A_y(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat y}+A_z(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat z}$, but a vector just $\mathbf{A}=A_x\mathbf{\hat x}+A_y\mathbf{\hat y}+A_z\mathbf{\hat z}$ (without an argument).

Answer (score 3):

@rushinc1 nearly had it.

The Lorentz force is sadly not a vector field in the normal sense (i.e. a smooth mapping from $(\vec r: \mathbb R^3, t : \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^3$), as you can see from the explicit presence of $\vec v$ in its definition: you *need* to know the velocity of the particle in order to calculate the magnetic force upon it, and that information is *not* contained merely in this information about where and when the Lorentz force is being evaluated.

It is sadly also not a 2-tensor field in the normal sense as its transformation of a velocity vector is *not* linear in that velocity vector (it is a sort of affine transformation because the $\vec E$ part is a sort of fixed constant).

However in special relativity it *does* become an antisymmetric 2-tensor field on the space of 4-vectors; the presence of the extra time component in the velocity 4-vector gives the tensor a perfect place to inject the $\vec E$ field alongside the $\vec B$ field. You get the antisymmetric 2-tensor $\partial_\alpha A_\beta - \partial_\beta A_\alpha$ (where $A^\mu$ is the standard 4-vector-potential) as a perfectly linear transformation of a four-velocity $U^\mu$ to a four-force $dp^\nu/d\tau,$ making it a clear 2-tensor.

Then in general relativity this again gets a little more complicated as there are many connections $\partial_\alpha$ to choose from, when we apply them to vectors, but the point is that in some generic sense anything that can be made out of well-defined 4-operators can be a 4-tensor.

Comment: Hi! How can I mathematically see that the Lorentz force isn't a vector field? I mean for $\mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B})$ we have: $$\mathbf F:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$$ $$\mathbf B:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$$ $$\mathbf v:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$$ $$t\in R $$So isn't the force explicit $\mathbf F(x,y,z)=q(\mathbf E(x,y,z)+\mathbf v(t)\times \mathbf B(x,y,z))?$

Comment: @JDoeDoe The problem is that $\vec v(t)$ is not a vector field. You can choose a $\vec v$ up front and then calculate a force field for all particles moving with that particular velocity, but since particles can have all sorts of different velocities that doesn't help you out much. The closest I can think would be that $\rho~\vec E + \vec J \times \vec B$ would be, assuming you "smear out" charge singularities over finite volumes, the force field of a bunch of charges on themselves.

Comment: In particular if one had a plasma probably there is a velocity field $\vec v$ over space and probably charge and mass densities are proportional with some factor $\mu$ and probably $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\mu~\rho~\vec v) + (\vec v \cdot \nabla) (\mu~\rho~\vec v) = \rho \vec E + \rho~\vec v\times\vec B - \nabla p$, this says that in a box moving downstream the momentum change is due to the Lorentz force on the charges in the box plus the pressure force from the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

The force pertains to a charged body moving along a trajectory given by the equation $ = (t)$, where I'm going to denote the function by a separate letter to remove the confusion. The velocity is $ = '(t)$. The force is involved in the force law:
$$\frac{d}{dt} =  = q( + ×)$$
which involves the charge's momentum $$ and is an expression of the time $t$, as are $(t)$ and $(t)$. The fields $$ and $$ are functions of $$ and $t$: $(,t)$ and $(,t)$, and are understood to be evaluated at the location of the charge.

So, the relevant expression - with all the function brackets and arguments made explicit - is:
$$(t) = '(t) = q(((t),t) + '(t)×((t),t)).$$
It is a vector-valued function of time, not a vector field.

Geometrically ...

The underlying geometry spanned by the coordinates $(,t)$ is a manifold $M$. The equation is an equation of mechanics, whose arena is actually *not* $M$, but a 1-dimensional "time manifold" $T$, spanned by the coordinate $t$.

You can think of $M$ as consisting of a copy of a 3D space $S_t$ at each time $t ∈ T$, the space $S_t$ being spanned by coordinates $_t$. It is a snapshot of 3D space at the time $t$. The set
$$\bigcup_{t ∈ T} \left(\{t\}×S_t\right) = \{ (t,_t): t ∈ T, _t ∈ S_t \},$$
is then the manifold $M$, itself, treated as a kind of geometry known as a *fiber bundle*. Each of the 3D snapshots $S_t$ is a *fiber*, this particular one being the fiber associated with $t$.

The 1D space $T$ - which is the arena of mechanics - is then called the "base space". When thought of as a fiber bundle over a base space, $M$ may be written as $M → T$. This is short for the (implied) "projection" map:
$$π: \left(t,_t\right) ∈ M ↦ t ∈ T$$
that gives you the base-space location for the entire fibre.

This layering of $M$ can be done in only one way in the geometry of non-relativistic theory, because the quality of being "simultaneous" (i.e "simultaneity") is an absolute, in it. In Special Relativity, however, it is not, so the layering can be done in many ways. In General Relativity, the layering can be done only if the underlying geometry is "globally hyperbolic", which is usually the assumption made, there.

So, we'll treat $M$ as a fiber bundle and equate it to the set just described above:
$$M = \bigcup_{t ∈ T} \{t\}×S_t.$$

Mechanics takes place over a 1D time manifold $T$. The various objects, such as $$, $$, $$, $$, when expressed as functions of time, might be considered "fields" over $T$, since they vary with position in $T$. So, time fields. For position, the actual function is given by the map:
$$: t ∈ T ↦  (t,(t)) ∈ \{t\} × S_t ⊆ M,$$
is called a "cross section" or "section" for short. The main property of a section is that it maps to the fiber over each point $t$ in the base space.

A section is an inverse of projection, since $π((t)) = t$. That's the main property used to define "section".

You can include the velocity as an *object* in the geometry, expanding the coordinate list to $\left(t, _t, _t\right)$. The geometry that has these as its coordinates is called a *jet bundle*, denoted here as $J^1M$. More accurately, it would be denoted $J^1π$, or $J^1(M → T)$, to make it clear which coordinates were with the base space and which ones were with the fibre. It's only the differentials of the fibre coordinates that are added into the jet bundle.

Each section in $M$ is then threaded into $J^1M$ as a "jet extension":
$$j^1: t ∈ T ↦ (t,(t),'(t)) ∈ J^1M.$$
That implements the "kinematic law":
$$_t = \frac{d_t}{dt}.$$

Presumably, $_t$ would be expressible, directly in terms of the coordinates of $J^1M$. For instance, in non-relativistic theory, one would have $_t = m _t$, while in relativity, it would be $_t = m _t/\sqrt{1 - |_t|^2/c^2}$. So, it lives in $J^1 M$.

So, if you ignore the time-dependency in the expression for the force, then it, too, can be expressed as an object in $J^1M$:
$$: \left(t,_t,_t\right) ∈ J^1M ↦ q\left(\left(_t,t\right) + _t×\left(_t,t\right)\right).$$
So, it *actually is* a vector-valued field ... but the field is over the whole geometry $J^1M$, since it is a function also of $$. When you made your comment about $$, that's when I first noticed the *real* question behind your question.

Your underlying question was: "where does $$ fit in all of this?" Well, that's where.

If your base space had more than one coordinate in it, then the jet extensions would be embodying partial derivatives, not ordinary derivatives, and sections over the base space would be "fields" in the more usual sense of the word. For a 1D base space $T$, sections or "time fields" are better known as just "trajectories".

Though it is not advertised as such, the jet bundle formalism is the *general* framework for ordinary and partial differential equations. It is nothing less than The General Mathematical Theory Of Differential Equations.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically a vector field is a vector valued function of spacetime coordinates only.  This makes it so we can talk about the source of a force independently from the object it acts on.

In order to describe the Lorentz force on an individual (ie, "test") particle you need to know both its position AND its velocity (as well as its charge, of course).  You cannot divide the force by a unit ("test") velocity, because velocity is itself a vector.  At best I suppose one could establish a Lorentz *tensor* field to serve a similar purpose, but to try to describe the Lorentz force via a *vector* field is nonsensical.

Now, that being said, if you have a collection of particles (like a fluid) that fill all of space and you can assign a velocity vector to each point in space at each time then you can generate something like a Lorentz vector field.  However, this is really more of an engineering trick to solve fluid dynamics problems and I personally would not consider it a vector field in the same sense as gravity or the electromagnetic field.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of the Lorentz force just as a electric vector field so $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)$. If I got you right, writing the Lorentz force in explicit form should be 
$\mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})+\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r})\times\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}))$ and NOT $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=q(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})+\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r})\times\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}))$? I.e. $\mathbf{F}$ is a not a function of space (or time).

Comment: I think you could write the second expression if you want to, but what is the meaning of **v(r)**?  If it's an individual particle then **v(r)** is a very peculiar kind of function that also depends on time (and is zero-valued everywhere but one point at any given time).

Comment: I was thinking of the fluid flow scenario too. I don't know why the downvote showed up - I can't see anything wrong with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In classical electromagnetism, the Lorentz force is just a vector and **NOT** a vector field. It can however be defined as a **tensor field** and that is exactly what it used when dealing with relativistic electromagnetism.

A vector field is a function that assigns an $n$ dimensional vector to each point in an $n$ dimensional space. The Lorentz force cannot be defined by such a field as we need information about **two** $n$ dimensional vectors ($\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$) for a complete description of the force.

When relativistic effects are also considered, the Lorentz force can be defined uniquely by the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Field_tensor)

$$\frac{dp^{\alpha}}{d\tau} = qF^{\alpha\beta}U_{\beta}$$

Here $F^{\alpha\beta}$ is the [electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) that can be considered equivalent to a *"Lorentz field"* of sorts.

Comment: *" The Lorentz force cannot be defined by such a field as we need information about two n dimensional vectors"* well, that doesn't make the Lorentz force any less of a vector field, according to your definition, the map being the assignment of both $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ at any point $(\mathbf{r},t)$. Moreover $F^{\alpha\beta}$ is **not** a tensor, rather they are the components of a tensor in a particular chart $U$ of the space-time manifold.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco that last point is incorrect; under abstract index notation $F^{\alpha\beta}$ is in fact the full-fledged tensor, not just a collection of components of it.